# Spock unit testing a Kotlin private static method

Tags: kotlin, gradle, spock

I'm looking for help to debug/resolve the obscure error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

I don't want to get into an argument of whether or not I should be testing a private method. But, I'm open to learning how to restructure this into something more testable that isn't exposed to the plugin user. I just can't seem to make it work. Below is the signature of the method and the relevant code.

### Output from println in test setup

```
public static final org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty my.project.MyPlugin.access$getResolvedDir(my.project.MyPlugin,java.lang.Object,org.gradle.api.Project)
```

### Class under test

```
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project): Unit = project.run {
        // do some gradle plugin stuff
        myTask.configure { dir = getResolvedDir(pluginExtension.dir, project) }
    }

    private fun getResolvedDir(dir: Any?, project: Project): DirectoryProperty {
        // do some stuff to transform the input to a DirectoryProperty
        return resolvedDir
    }
}
```

### Spock test case

```
class MyPluginTest extends Specification {

    @Rule
    public final TemporaryFolder testProjectDir = new TemporaryFolder()
    private Project p
    private MyPlugin plugin
    private CachedMethod getResolvedDirMethod

    def setup() {
        p = ProjectBuilder.builder().withName("install-plugin-test").build()
        plugin = new InstallPlugin()
        plugin.metaClass.methods.each {
            if (it.name.contains("getResolvedDir"))
                getResolvedDirMethod = it
        }
        getResolvedDirMethod.setAccessible()
        println getResolvedDirMethod
    }

    def "String resolution for dir"() {
        when:
        def x = "xyz"

        then:
        DirectoryProperty dir = getResolvedDirMethod.invoke(plugin, x, p)
    }
}
```

Comment: The details are vague (a stack trace would be nice), but my guess is this has to do with static typing and the `invoke` method. You probably need to change the call to `invoke` to `invoke(plugin, [x, p] as Object[])`. As for testing private methods, consider using the packages and package-private such that your tests can access the methods but developers cannot.

Comment: `internal` seems to be the answer. Avoid this whole reflection nonsense and switched from private to internal. Feel free to post as an answer or I will. I'm still interested to see what I did wrong with the reflection. So, I have a working solution now...perhaps I needed more sleep before going through the trouble of creating this question. ;)

Comment: IMO the answer is much simpler. I am sure you have heard it before: Do not directly test private methods at all. Try to cover them by testing public methods using suitable parameter sets. In your case, `project` is a parameter of `apply()` and wherever `pluginExtension.dir` comes from, you can manipulate it in order to modify the private method's other parameter. Then test for the desired side effect of `apply()`. There is no other way because it is what in Java would be called `void`, so you cannot check the return value. But `internal` works too, if you insist on direct testing.

Comment: That's a fair statement. The testing here definitely needs to be improved. As usual, time constraints find me juggling doing the "best thing" with "just trying to make sure the new thing I added works". 

I guess I was too narrowly focused. The only thing my testing is avoiding is the trouble of creating several different ProjectBuilder configurations to test the apply, as you said. But, again, you are more right than my approach.

Comment: Having said all of that, I'm still keen to know what is wrong with my reflection attempt.